# onchange addresses the quantity box validation, why does Enter key gets passed?

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

```
<h:inputText id="quantity"
value="#{_cartItem.quantity}" required="true" size="3"
maxlength="3">
<f:converter converterId="ValueConverter" />
<f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="999" />
<a:support event="onchange"
    ajaxSingle="true"
    action="#{cSession.userCheckQuantity(_cartItem, index)}"
    reRender="minicartAjax, shoppingCartAjax, orderTotalAjax"></a:support>
```

When you click off the Quantity input box the userCheckQuantity method is easily fired. But If I put in a number and quickly slam down the enter key on the keyboard the validation is missed.

How can I get the Enter key approach to validate as well?  Let me know if I need to provide more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the validation by Ajax exclusively. This is not robust enough. You need to replace the `action="#{cSession.userCheckQuantity(_cartItem, index)}"` by a fullworthy [`Validator`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html) implementation which you bind to the input component as a `<f:validator>`. This way the validation will always take place, regardless of whether it's been triggered by a change or a form submit.

Inside the `Validator` implementation, you could obtain the `_cartItem` and `index` from the `FacesContext`. How exactly depends on where they are stored and what JSF spec version you're using. If they're for example stored as request attributes, you could use `ExternalContext#getRequestMap()` to get them.